# Is there a faster way to search for a record that has records in another table?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know if there was a more efficient way to find what I'm looking for.

Items have stats
Stats are stored in a separate table linked with an item_id.
An item will have multiple stats.

To make an item drop with specific stats my code generates a SQL statement like below, to find these items.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT *
   FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM 
      (SELECT *
       FROM items
       WHERE items.item_type = :item_type
         AND items.power_level < :power_level
         AND items.power_level > :power_level_lowest) AS i
     WHERE EXISTS (
       SELECT id
       FROM item_stat
       WHERE item_stat.stat_id = :stat_1
       AND i.id = item_stat.item_id)
   ) AS i1 
   WHERE EXISTS (
     SELECT id
     FROM item_stat
     WHERE item_stat.stat_id = :stat_2
       AND i1.id = item_stat.item_id)
) AS i2  
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT id
  FROM item_sta
  WHERE item_stat.stat_id = :stat_3
    AND i2.id = item_stat.item_id)
ORDER BY power_level DESC;
```

Is there a faster way to search for items with specific stats in another table, there are about 500k records in items.  Between 50-80k for each item_type each with between 4-7 stats totals. but the searches only need to verify an item has 1-4.

I'm using MariaDB to host these records.  The query works it just takes longer than I want it too.

To clarify the requirements: 
There are many items with lots of different stats.
I want to find all the items sorted by power level that must contain at least the specified specific stats.

The items must have the stats but do contain more. Right now I'm using a separate query to retrieve the complete data afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not very clear, and I may have misunderstood your problem. But from what I've got, I think you can do what you want to do with just a few `JOIN` operations:

```sql
SELECT items.*
FROM items
  JOIN item_stat AS stat1
    ON stat1.stat_id = :stat_1
    AND stat1.item_id = items.id
  JOIN item_stat AS stat2
    ON stat2.stat_id = :stat_2
    AND stat2.item_id = items.id
  JOIN item_stat AS stat3
    ON stat3.stat_id = :stat_3
    AND stat3.item_id = items.id
WHERE items.item_type = :item_type
  AND items.power_level < :power_level
  AND items.power_level > :power_level_lowest
ORDER BY items.power_level DESC;
```

If this does not work like you want it to, can you please update your question with some examples of `items` and `item_stat` data, along with the expected result?

Comment: I'm currently regenerating the items so I cant test to see your results.  This will take a few hours. but I will check this above query and compare the speed.

To clarify the question.  
The items have many stats, I want to find all the items sorted by power level that must contain at least the specified specific stats.  
The items must have the stats but do contain more.  Right now I'm using a separate query to retrieve the complete data afterwards.

Comment: I tested the query at it went form 9.5seconds to run to 0.35seconds

Are there any other optimisations which could improve this further?

Comment: I don't see any drastic optimizations on the query itself, but maybe you can improve the performances by working with [indexes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-indexes.htm) if you don't have any already